# HTML button not linking to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys just having an issue with my HTML button not actually running my javascript function when clicked on.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PROJECT</title>
<script language="javascript" src="Hangman.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <input id = "Begin" type = "button" value = "Play">       
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS:

```
function start () 
    {
     document.getElementById("Begin").addEventListener("click",logic,false);
    }

function logic () 
    {
        document.writeln("yo");
    }

 window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

Sorry if this is an amateur question, it just so happens I'm an amateur. Thanks you guys in advance!

Comment: I just made two files: index.htm (with your HTML) and Hangman.js (with your JS). Your code works for me. Do you have Javascript turned on and is your file named Hangman.js in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: add alert("HI"); in first line of your js code to make sure it's loaded :-)

Comment: you could use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start())`

Answer (score 1):

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxdvgcrf/)
it is fixed

```
function start () 
    {
     document.getElementById("Begin").addEventListener("click",logic,false);
    }

function logic () 
    {
       alert();
    }

window.onLoad=start();
```